# New program with appcelerator don't run

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-alloy

I've created a new app in Appcelerator and it doesn't run. The project gets created but it doesn't let me write any code.

I've created the project with via `File -> New -> Mobile App Project` and then `Default Alloy Project`.

After creation I got the following message in my `TiApp.xml`:

"The project has an invalid/non-platform GUID and cannot be run. Please register the app with the platform." And i have a button to do this "Register app".

Please help me. Thanks

Comment: are you a paying customer of appcelerator? And have you tried removing/replacing the `guid` in tiapp and then re-running? When you re-run with a new guid it will ask if you want to register the app if you're at least an indie developer

Comment: yes, i'm a indie developer. i only create a new project. and i don't touch anything of tiapp.xml generated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open Terminal, go to my/path/project and type `appc new --import` to register app